# How to run for loop in buildspec file of AWS CodeBuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-codebuild

I am trying to run a for loop to traverse multiple folders in the cloned code using the following method

```
commands:
- folders=`ls`
- for value in ${folders}
- do
- some_code_here
- done
```

Also, I've tried different ways like

```
- for value in ${folders}; do
- some_code_here
- done
```

But none of them works.

Answer (score 9):

You should write for-loops as one-liner. As CodeBuild merges all lines in one command together, you can write for-loops in a readable format as follows:

```
- folders=`ls`
- for value in $folders;
   do
      echo $value;
   done
- echo "run the next command"
```

Comment: Thank you for this, where you have `echo $value;` there I am running `npm test`, its failing but AWS codebuild isn't reporting a failure. I think it maybe because it only evaluates lines with a "-" and the for loop always reports success.

Comment: Just make sure that npm test returns a non-zero exit code on failures. try it out in a shell and check the result using "echo $?". For loops in Bash return the exit code of the last command run inside the loop, so it looks like npm returns zero and CodeBuild doesn't reports success.

Comment: I got it to work using `npm install || exit 1` and its working, not 100% sure why `exit 1` was required. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use YAML multiline string.

```yaml
- |
  for value in ${folders}; do
    some_code_here
  done
```